# Gatling load tests and ScalaTest unit tests in same Play project

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework-2.0, scalatest, gatling

We have been using ScalaTestPlusPlay for the tests in our project so far, but
recently decided to try out some Gatling load tests. We want 3
groups of tests that can be run separately:

1. Plain unit tests   (via "test")
2. Integration tests  (via "it:test")
3. Load tests         (via "gatling-it:test")

Unfortunately I have only either been able to get groups 1&2 or 2&3 to be
available at any given time. If the Gatling plugin is not enabled, the unit
tests and integration tests can be executed.

But if I add:

```
enablePlugins(GatlingPlugin)
```

to build.sbt, I gain the ability to run the Gatling load tests, but at
the expense of the original unit tests. The "test" task can still be executed,
but no test classes are found/ran.

built.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1100-jdbc4",
  "org.flywaydb" % "flyway-sbt" % "3.0",
  "org.dbunit" % "dbunit" % "2.5.1" % "test,it",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test,it",
  "org.scalatestplus" %% "play" % "1.4.0-M3",
  "org.jdom" % "jdom" % "1.1.2"  notTransitive(),
  "org.pac4j" % "play-pac4j-scala_2.11"  % "1.5.0",
  "org.pac4j" % "pac4j-http" % "1.7.1",
  "jp.t2v" %% "play2-auth"      % "0.13.2",
  "jp.t2v" %% "play2-auth-test" % "0.13.2" % "test,it",
  "javax.jms" % "javax.jms-api" % "2.0.1",
  "org.apache.activemq" % "activemq-all" % "5.11.1",
  "io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "2.1.7" % "test",
  "io.gatling"            % "gatling-test-framework"    % "2.1.7" % "test",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.4.0",
  jdbc,
  ws,
  cache
)

Defaults.itSettings

lazy val ItTest = config("it") extend(Test)

lazy val GatlingTest = config("gatling-it") extend(ItTest) 

enablePlugins(GatlingPlugin)

def loadTestFilter(name: String): Boolean = (name endsWith "LoadTest")

def itTestFilter(name: String): Boolean = (name endsWith "IntegrationTest")

def unitTestFilter(name: String): Boolean = ((name endsWith "Suite"))

sourceDirectory in IntegrationTest := baseDirectory.value / "test/it"

testOptions in Gatling := Seq(Tests.Filter(loadTestFilter))

testOptions in ItTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(itTestFilter))

testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Filter(unitTestFilter))

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .configs(ItTest) settings( inConfig(ItTest)(Defaults.testTasks) : _*)

// Failed attempt at isolating gatling tests
lazy val gatling = project.in(file("."))
  .enablePlugins(GatlingPlugin)
))
```

project/plugins.sbt

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.2")  // It works from Play 2.3.2

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-gzip" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("org.scalastyle" %% "scalastyle-sbt-plugin" % "0.6.0")

// Generate ctags for project. Yes, I am probably the only one who cares
addSbtPlugin("net.ceedubs" %% "sbt-ctags" % "0.1.0")

resolvers += "sonatype-releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.1")

// Gatling Stress Testing
addSbtPlugin("io.gatling" % "gatling-sbt" % "2.1.7")
```

So how can I get access to the new Gatling tests without losing all the unit
tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maintainer of Gatling's SBT plugin here.

You're unfortunately not the first to bump into this issue, and I'm working on a fix.
As a temporary workaround, you can get your unit tests back and running by using `test:test` instead of `test`.
It should be fixed for Gatling 2.1.8 ;)

Comment: Quick update: this has been fixed, it will definitely get in 2.1.8 !

Answer (score 3):

I usually move gatling into a sub-project like this, in build.sbt:

```
lazy val gtl = Project("gtl", File("gtl")).settings(....).enablePlugins(GatlingPlugin)
aggregate in Test := false
```

then execute via sbt

```
gtl/it:test or gtl/test
```

Comment: What are some advantages to this subproject approach, aside from being able to use the "test" command without a namespace prefix?

Comment: @swoogles mainly not polluting build files with test specific options like jvm runtime  and conflicting libraries. And yes, that was a workaround the bug mentioned above.